# Recording rental deposit return minus cleaning fees

Tags: bookkeeping, lease

This is a question about Double-Entry Bookkeeping. I am having a hard time correctly recording the fact that **due to shared cleaning fees I owe the subleasee less than the deposit he gave me.**

These are the actual events:

1. I rented an apartment and put down $1000 in deposit.
2. Then I sublet it, and received a $500 deposit.
3. Then the lease ended and we got charged $200 in cleaning fees, which we agreed to split 50/50.
4. I received $800 from the landlord
5. I paid the subleasee $400.

How should I record this to reflect that my liability towards him decreased by the amount of the cleaning fees?

Answer (score 6):

I would work it something like this.

You pay the landlord the deposit:

```
Accounts:Checking             1000
Rental:Deposit          1000
```

Your subleasee pays you his deposit, which you track separately:

```
Accounts:Checking        500
Rental:Sublease:Deposit        500
```

Your landlord pays you back the deposit, less the cleaning fee:

```
Accounts:Checking        800
Rental:Cleaning          200
Rental:Deposit                1000
```

You pay the subleasee his deposit back, less his share of the cleaning fee:

```
Accounts:Checking              400
Rental:Cleaning                100
Rental:Sublease:Deposit  500
```

Adding that up you should have the following balances:

```
Accounts:Checking             -100
Rental:Deposit                   0
Rental:Sublease:Deposit          0
Rental:Cleaning                100
```

Comment: Perfect, so what I was missing is that the $500 liability in Rental:Sublease:Deposit can be cancelled by taking $100 out of the expense account Rental:Cleaning.
Thank you! This makes a lot of sense.